# Cannot remove html tags without triggering error

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to run this simple code where I parse some information from a site and return only the information between the  tags.

Code below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as reg
import csv
import re


url = ('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
response = reg.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('div', class_='body')
header = data.find_all('th')
print(header.text)
```

I'm trying to return:

`Program Name Internet Points Kittens?`

However, this returns error message:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Now when I remove the .text I can get

`[<th>Program Name</th>, <th>Internet Points</th>, <th>Kittens?</th>]`

But obviously I want the  tags removed.

Any help please?

Thanks ^_^

Comment: `find_all()` returns a `list`, not a single tag. So either you have to use `find()` or iterate through the list to get a single tag and retrieve the text.

Comment: So is it because the .text function removes just tags from a section of html but because there's other shit in the list then it won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, `find_all` returns a list of items, not a single item. The problem is not that there is other stuff in the list, it is that you *have* a list, and `.text` is defined to work not on a list but on a single item. Does this work better (a little closer to your original code):

```
headers = data.find_all('th')
for header in headers:
    print(header.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now ^^